# Best way to transfer option data from one form back to the main form

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a main form that loads and immediately start receiving data from a serial port every 0.5 seconds.

I then want to load a set of settings and to do this I plan on having a options button on the main form which loads a separate form with a drop down list of the different pre-set option sets.

What is the best way to get the option that has been selected back to the main form and then act upon receiving it?

With my current setup I have have a separate class which contains some global variables. When I click apply in the options form it fires the selected set name to that global variable which is then checked from the main form after the dialogue box / form closes.

I am using C# .Net 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on complexity of operations you use. 
But simple solution could be :

- open configuration form like Dialog
- on it's close (Ok button clicked, DialogResult == OK) just re-read(reload) entire configuration and rerun your communication with COM port.

Hope this helps.